# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, r, reticulate, pvlib

I enountered

> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) :    AttributeError:
>   'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

on calling python code in R using reticulate package in R.

The code in python runs correctly. I am not sure from where this error is coming. I am using pvlib python library to call some in build databases.

My code is for R is:

```
library('reticulate')
pd <- import('pandas')
pvlib <- import('pvlib')
np <- import('numpy') 
sandia_modules = pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam("CECInverter")
```

I have issue with `cec_inverters = pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam("CECInverter")` when I the code in python it's working but running same commands in R is giving me error. I am not sure what the issue is. Please help me resolve this issue.

The similar code in python is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pvlib

sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('cecinverter')
```

I tried looking for solution but so far didn't find anything useful.

Here's the traceback:

```
10: stop(list(message = "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'", 
        call = py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent), cppstack = list(
            file = "", line = -1L, stack = "C++ stack not available on this system")))
9: .Call(`_reticulate_py_get_attr_impl`, x, name, silent)
8: py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent)
7: py_get_attr(x, name)
6: `$.python.builtin.object`(x[[column]], "dtype")
5: x[[column]]$dtype
4: py_to_r(x[[column]]$dtype$name)
3: py_to_r.pandas.core.frame.DataFrame(result)
2: py_to_r(result)
1: pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam("CECInverter")
```

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: you can check now.

Comment: That's not a full error traceback.  There should be one line for each frame of the call stack.  Not just one line deep somewhere we don't know.

Comment: Why do you have `cecinverter` in Python but `CECInverter` in R?  Can you try changing the case in R to match Python?

Comment: both works in python. So that's not an issue. Even if I type 'sandiamod' instead of 'SandiaMod' it works.

Comment: OK, well, let us know when you can provide a full stack trace.

Comment: @JohnZwinck check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `as` parameter in `import()`. Your code errored for me as well but this worked:

```
library(reticulate) # version 1.6

pd <- import('pandas', as = "pd")
pvlib <- import('pvlib', as = "pvlib")
np <- import('numpy', as = "np") 

sandia_modules <- pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters <- pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam("CECInverter")
```

Comment: Wow this is truly insane.  Do you have any explanation for why this code works but the original fails?  The examples from the `reticulate` docs look like OP's code, not like this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck many things working like that (strangely). Initially I had problem with `pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')` but I uninstalled `reticulate` package and installed again. It was like there was no issue. Now I am having issue with accessing stuff from my databases. `sandia_module = sandia_modules["Canadian_Solar_CS5P_220M___2009_"]` This line of code was working perfectly before with `sandia_modules` but it is giving an Error now: `object of type 'environment' is not subsettable` Not sure why things working so strange. One time they work and other time behaving opposite

Comment: found this solution to my latest issue: "(COPIED): I used [[ rather than [ because the former does single element indexing whereas the latter can select ranges via logical vectors." If that was the case why I was able to access before. Ridiculous..

Comment: I haven't been able to fully trace what's happening in `reticulate` to cause this but I've seen it with DataFrame ops when other module code has things like https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/2d08caaa5e94c9b4f70de4c267483c47dacae935/pvlib/forecast.py#L7-L8 in it. In reality, only the `pd <- import('pandas', as = "pd")` is rly needed but it also doesn't hurt to mimic the python `import x as y` with the `as = ` `import()` param.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this long back but posting here now that `"reticulate"` package from GitHub is the latest one and many issues has been address within this version. The main one being `pandas` `DataFrame` conversion to R `data.frame`

Here's the code to do so

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
```