# Pandas Error for creating an emptydataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried making a dummy dataframe,

`column_names = ["a", "b", "c"]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)`

I am getting the following error, this was not happening before, am I missing something. This is only happening on the creation of an empty dataframe, is this a recently introduced bug.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 411, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 242, in init_dict
    val = construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(np.nan, len(index), nan_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1221, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar
    dtype = dtype.dtype
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

[image: Sample code]

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: What else is going on in your code?

Comment: This is all I am trying, in the terminal @Epsi95

Comment: @goalie1998 This is all I am trying, in the terminal

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197832/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-dtype

Comment: @Vaishali I checked that out, the question is different

Comment: Which version of pandas do you use? I am not able to reproduce the error in pandas 1.1.4.

Comment: @mosc9575 pandas==0.25.3

Comment: Maybe it solves your problem when you try to update your pandas.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This was happening with `pandas==0.25.3`
Updated to the latest `pandas==1.2.1`

UPDATE:
This was due to a numpy package `1.20.0`,
so I locked the numpy package instead, `numpy==1.19.5`, `pandas==0.25.3`

Answer (score 39):

If for some reason you don't/can't upgrade numpy/pandas, an alternative way to fix this is by specifiying the dtype when creating the DataFrame. For example:

```
column_names = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names, dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 6):

happening due to `numpy==1.20.0`, and resolve with `numpy==1.19.5`.
pandas version may not relevant, in my case, `pandas==1.0.4`

Answer (score 2):

pandas version was the problem in my case.

It should work if you shift from

`pandas==0.25.3` into `pandas==1.2.3`

Answer (score 0):

Solved local script redefining data frame
header=['A','B','C','D','E']

```
    # MemorySummary=pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
    # broken after pandas update?
    # AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
    
    MemorySummary=pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 5)))
    MemorySummary.set_axis( header, axis=1, inplace=True)
```