# Plotly express not rendering a sunburst chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I am trying to create a sunburst chart using a pandas dataframe and plotly express.

Here is dataframe, keep in mind this is only the first 10 rows, once it finishes with the suburbs for 2001, it jumps to the same suburbs for 2006, 2011, 2016

[image]

And here is my code

```
sunburst_chart = px.sunburst(
    sunburst_data,
    path=["year", "neighbourhood"],
    values="average_house_value",
    names="neighbourhood",  
)

sunburst_chart.show()
```

The error that is gives me is `AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'` and is referring to `names="neighbourhood"` but if I remove that line the error points to the line above, and repeat.

There are no duplicate rows, no nulls and the dtypes are

```
year                    int64
neighbourhood          object
average_house_value     int64
dtype: object
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please don't post images. People can't copy data from the image and reproduce your problem -

Comment: @Psidom What do you want me to put in its place? My df is like 700 rows

Comment: Paste a small data frame as text that can reproduce your problem. You don't need to put 700 rows in the post

Comment: What version of numpy and pandas are you using?

Comment: @TomWeekes I find it best to share samples of data [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998646/pandas-error-for-creating-an-emptydataframe) and [this bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39520), I believe this is a numpy and pandas related bug that should be solved if you upgrade to the latest version of both libraries.

I created a sample DataFrame with the same columns and data types as yours, and after I downgraded to `pandas 0.25.3 / numpy 1.20.0`, I was able to reproduce your error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'.
```

When I upgraded both libraries to `numpy 1.21.0 / pandas 1.1.0`, I was able to generate a sunburst plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

sunburst_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'year':[2001]*4 + [2002]*4 + [2003]*4,
    'neighbourhood': list('abcdefghijkl'),
    'average_house_value': list(range(100000,220000,10000))
})

sunburst_chart = px.sunburst(
    sunburst_data,
    path=["year", "neighbourhood"],
    values="average_house_value",
    names="neighbourhood",  
)

sunburst_chart.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @TomWeekes If this suggestion solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer and / or give it an upvote!